# How do I configure my pom to use one log4j.properties file for main and test?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, pom.xml

I have a log4j.properties file in src/main/resources.  When I run my tests only console logging occurs, but not file appender logging.  I would like to point to the same properties file for my tests.

I've learned this is possible to do in my pom file with a the test scope and a -D argument.  How is this done?

Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
# ROOT CATEGORY is used to set level of logger and appender name 
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, CA, RA 
# DEBUG is a root level and FA, CA, DA are appender name (appender name can be different) 

# ---------- CA is set to be a ConsoleAppender ---------- 

# Write to Console(stdout or stderr). 
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
# This appender will only log messages with priority equal to or higher than the one specified here 
# hierarchy of level is (from lower to higher): DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR,FATAL 
log4j.appender.CA.Threshold=DEBUG 
# appender layouts (log formats) 
#log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout 
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
# For a pattern layout, specify the pattern (Default is %m%n which is fastest) 
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %c - %m%n 

# ---------- RA is set to be a RollingFileAppender ---------- 

# Write log to a file, roll the file after some size 
log4j.appender.RA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
# This appender will only log messages with priority equal to or higher than the one specified here 
log4j.appender.RA.Threshold=DEBUG 
# The name of log file 
log4j.appender.RA.File= \log4j.log 
# The maximum log file size 
log4j.appender.RA.MaxFileSize=10MB 
# Don't append, overwrite 
#log4j.appender.RA.Append=false 
# Keep backup file(s) (backups will be in filename.1, .2 etc.) 
log4j.appender.RA.MaxBackupIndex=1 
# appender layouts (log formats) 
#log4j.appender.RA.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout 
log4j.appender.RA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
# For a pattern layout, specify the pattern (Default is %m%n which is fastest) 
log4j.appender.RA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add command line settings/system properties to the test runner. I asume you use surefire, then it is done like [this](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <log4j.configuration>log4j.properties</ log4j.configuration>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```